# Generate Amazon link for open side popup with pre-applied filters

Tags: html, hyperlink, tags

Edit: Stackoverflow modify automatically the Amazon links when you click, so for see the popup, select, copy and paste the URLs in the browser.

On Amazon there is a link to open directly a side popup, like this:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07FKTZC4M/#aod](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FKTZC4M) (#aod open the popup)

where We can enter some filters. I tried different ways with no success to generate a link that open directly the site popup **with new filter pre-applied**.

So i need a link that open this page with "new filter" pre-applied:

[image]

I tried different solutions, but don't work, for example:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07FKTZC4M/ref=aod_f_new#aod](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FKTZC4M)

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07FKTZC4M/ref=new#aod](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FKTZC4M)

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07FKTZC4M/#aod_f_new=true](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FKTZC4M)

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07FKTZC4M/ref=aod_f_new=true#aod](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FKTZC4M)

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07FKTZC4M/ref=aod_f_new?ie=UTF8&f_new=true#aod](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FKTZC4M)

I see some informations on source page, maybe that help:

[image]

Question: Is there a way to create a link that open directly the side popup with new filter pre-applied? Maybe adding some parameters to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function in JavaScript with which you can change the `z-index` of the popup.
Something like this:

```
<button onclick="popup()" value="open popup">
```

Also make the popup. I am just making a rough one:

```
<div id="popup" style="z-index:1000; position: absolute;">Some code</div>
```

Remember to set the `z-index` at behind and the `position`. Then for JS i will make it simple in case you can't code JS

```js
function popup(){
document.getElementById("popup").style.zIndex=-1;//basically changing the popup's z-index
}
```

This will just change the `z-index` of the popup which you must create yourself

Comment: Thanks Shiven Dhir, but this is not what i asked. I only need a link URL that open directly the side popup with new filter pre-applied

Comment: I am sorry I  was unable to answer your question but I do have a second suggestion: Maybe if you also add the tag of PHP and JavaScript you might get help